# Can I mix joint compounds with different setting times to get a custom setting time?

Tags: drywall, plaster

I'm currently skim coating some really bad looking walls and my 45 minute joint compound is setting too fast for me to get a nice finish.

Can I mix the remainder of my 45 minute Joint Compound with a new bag of 210 minute JC to get something in-between?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is yes.  I have done this but not for the reasons you have stated.  I just had some leftovers and wanted to use them.  As long as your mixing agent - water - is the same then mix away.  Note that other than trial and error you are looking at a setting time between 45 mins to 210 mins - even if you mixed 50/50.

Comment: Great, thanks!  I am mixing also because I have leftovers, but I was hoping for a slightly shorter drying time as well.

Comment: There are 'kickers' and retarders for the 'hot' JC dry mixes.  You have to go to a drywall supplies to find them.